# Trouble using Ray.Intersect method on bounding boxes in a 2D XNA game

Tags: xna, c#

I am trying to use a ray and bounding box to determine if a box is between the player and the mouse pointer in 2D space.  When I try testing the code, the collision will return true when pointed at the box but it also returns true under other circumstances where it shouldn't.

For instance.  If I have a player on the left and a box directly to the right, I can put the mouse pointer a few hundred pixels above the box or a few hundred below and it will still return true.  Also, I can put my mouse pointer to the left of the player and in a certain area it will still return true.  Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?

I have left out definitions for some of my members and properties just to make this code sample easier to read.  The position property is just a Vector2 for where each object is located.

```
ray = new Ray(new Vector3(player.Position, 0), new Vector3(mouse.Position, 0);
box = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(box.Position, 0), new Vector3(
new Vector2(box.Position + box.Width, box.Position + box.Height), 0);

if (ray.Intersects(box) != null)
    collision = true;
else
    collision = false;
```

Comment: When you debug, what values are stored in `ray` and `box`?

Comment: Here is an example of values I get.  The ray is pointed in the opposite direction of the box but still returns a value, and a strange value of less than 2.  I don't get it.

ray origin: {X:350 Y:350 Z:0}
ray destination: {X:82 Y:88 Z:0}
box points: {X:500 Y:540 Z:0}
{X:600 Y:540 Z:0}
{X:600 Y:500 Z:0}
{X:500 Y:500 Z:0}
{X:500 Y:540 Z:0}
{X:600 Y:540 Z:0}
{X:600 Y:500 Z:0}
{X:500 Y:500 Z:0}
collision distance: 1.829268

Comment: The order in which those points are inserted makes a lot of difference.  Bounding box can get confused if it's various `Min` and `Max` coordinates are swapped.  That came up for this post: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54382/bounding-boxes-and-xna/54384#54384

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain this is the cause, but I do notice an issue when I looked up `Ray`'s documentation. `Ray`'s first argument is a position (so okay there). `Ray`'s second argument expects a `Vector`. Coding-wise, the two are interchangable, but concept-wise, they're very different. Basically, the second argument should just indicate which *direction* for that Ray to face from its starting point; not which position it should point towards.

I think `mouse.position - player.position` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the bounding box has the same Z in Max and Min, so there is no volume.

Changing this:

```
 box = new BoundingBox(
    new Vector3(box.Position, 0), 
    new Vector3( new Vector2(box.Position + box.Width, box.Position + box.Height), 0);
```

To this:

```
 box = new BoundingBox(
    new Vector3(box.Position, 0), 
    new Vector3( new Vector2(box.Position + box.Width, box.Position + box.Height), 1);
```

Should work..

I thing your over complicating things a bit... Is easier using a rectangle for this without using rays and boundingboxes:

```
Reectangle bounds = new Rectangle((int) pos.X, (int) pos.Y, 0,0);
bounds.Inflate(size/2, size/2);

if (bounds.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y) {
  ....
}
```

Or using distance if it's suitable:

if (Vector2.Distance(playerPos, mousePos)